# Polymorphic (derived model referred) model inheritance in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following inheritance structure of my Django models:

- `Transaction`

  - `SimpleTransaction`
  - `SubscriptionTransaction`
- `Item`

  - `SimpleItem`
  - `SubscriptionItem`

The model `SimpleTransaction` refers to the model `SimpleItem` and the class `SubscriptionTransaction` refers to the model `SubscriptionItem`.

The most obvious way to do this is to define `item` field in `Transaction`:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    # ...
    item = models.ForeignKey('Item')
    # ...
```

But I would like `t.item` to refer to `SimpleItem` or `SubscriptionItem` (not the base class `Item` as in the above code) dependently on whether `t` is `SimpleTransaction` or `SubscriptionTransaction`.

What are the ways to do this in Django?

Or maybe referring to a derived class (`SimpleItem` or `SubscriptionItem`) instead of `Item` may somehow impact performance badly, as it would request to read `SimpleItem` or `SubscriptionItem` even when just `Item` fields are needed? and so better to refer to the base class and not to invent a question like this? However having references to a particular `Item`-derived class (not just `Item` base class) from either `SimpleTransaction` or `SubscriptionTransaction` benefits referential integrity. So should I do this to improve the DB "stability"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative solution would be to have separate `item` for "simple" and "subscription" classes:

```
class SimpleTransaction(models.Model):
    # ...
    item = models.ForeignKey('SimpleItem')
    # ...
# ...

class SubscriptionTransaction(models.Model):
    # ...
    item = models.ForeignKey('SubscriptionItem')
    # ...
```

But this way there would be no direct way (without using a conditional operator or like this) to refer to a related transaction from an item:

```
i.simpletransaction if i.simpletransaction else i.subscriptiontransaction
```

So I rule out this way as non-acceptable.

It is possible to add these properties, however:

```
class SimpleTransaction(Transaction):
    @property
    def simple_item(self):
        return self.item.simpleitem

class SubscriptionTransaction(Transaction):
    @property
    def subscription_item(self):
        return self.item.subscriptionitem
```

I see no other ways to tackle this problem.